# How do I check if my postfix email server is using SSL?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, ssl, letsencrypt

I have an Ubuntu mail server running postfix version 3.6.4. I configured postfix to use ssl by adding the following lines to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/host-name.domain.name/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/host-name.domain.name/privkey.pem
```

I am successfully receiving emails from a gmail account. How do I ensure that the emails are ssl encrypted?

Comment: *I am successfully receiving emails from a gmail account.* - what does that mean?

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov That means I'm sending my test emails over the internet (via a gmail account) to an address on my mail server, as opposed to sending the test email locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the mail logs will have a line similar to this if postfix is receiving email with encryption...

`2022-08-11T19:17:07.707481+01:00 eth6 postfix/smtpd[8401]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail[1.2.3.4]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange ECDHE (P-256) server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256`

You can also telnet to the local smtp port and type in `helo moto` then `ehlo b.org` and it should then tell you what it supports. Look for a line similar to `250-STARTTLS` The `moto` and `b.org` are just pointless drivel and can be anything.

Yet another way, is to look at the raw output of a received email message. You should see output similar to:

```
Received: from mail.nowhere.com (mail.nowhere.com [2.3.4.5])
    (using TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
     key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256)
    (Client did not present a certificate)
    by gate.nowhere.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 9D3F880E984F
    for <j@nowhere.com>; Fri, 15 Jul 2022 19:12:02 +0100 (BST
```

As for sending, just run `tcpdump` and send an email to some gmail account and look at the ascii output.